# Leaflet html widget (sparkline) in popup

Tags: r, r-leaflet

Popups and labels reportedly can have arbitrary html as their content. I would like to add eg a sparkline to a popup or label in `leaflet` using R, hopefully without needing to learn javascript.

I have tried pasting the html content of the output of `sparkline()` into the label parameter and calling `sparkline()` directly without luck.

````
---
title: "delme"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(tidyverse)
library(leaflet)
library(sparkline)
```

```{r minex}

leaflet() %>% 
  addTiles() %>%
  addPopups(-122.327298, 47.597131, sparkline(c(1, 5, 2, 8)))

```
````

Comment: maybe [this](https://github.com/r-spatial/mapview/issues/30) is a starting point